# How to return pandas upper and lower for bins as floats?

Tags: python, pandas, bin

When i bin a column, I want to return the upper and lower values of the bins as floats. how do you do that?

> current_bin = [Interval(39.976, 40.682, closed='right')]

to which i can get down to:

> current_bin[0]=(15.966, 16.672]

but i want to return

> lower_bin = 15.966

> upper_bin = 16.67

I don't recognize what it's returning. I can't subscript it, or turn it into a list.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Check [`pandas.Interval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html), you can use

```py
lower_bin = current_bin[0].left
upper_bin = current_bin[0].right
```

If you want to get `left` from a list of `pandas.Interval`, you can also try

```py
lower_bins = pd.arrays.IntervalArray(current_bin).left
```